# Set AutoDelete after when setting receive endpoint after bus has started

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using masstransit/rabbitmq in net core 3.1. I have a dispatcher service which will send messages to worker services when they are available. Each worker service has a rabbitmq queue in front which is created when the service starts. I want to make sure that when the worker service stops, then the queue(and exchange) needs to be deleted.  I have been able to get it to work when I set flag AutoDelete in the configuration (Program.cs):

```
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                config.Host(settings.RabbitMq.Host, settings.RabbitMq.Port,
                    settings.RabbitMq.VirtualHost, h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(settings.RabbitMq.Username);
                        h.Password(settings.RabbitMq.Password);
                    });

                var queueName = AssembleQueueName(settings);

                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                config.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName,
                    e =>
                    {
                        e.Consumer(() => new MessageConsumer());
                        e.AutoDelete = true;
                    });
            }));
        });
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me because I need have the ServiceProvider in my consumer class so therefore I'm doing the following instead (Worker.cs):

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var queueName = _settings.RabbitMq.ServicePrefixQueueName + "-" + _settings.ServiceId;

        var messageHandler = _busControl.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(queueName, x =>
        {
            x.Consumer<MessageConsumer>(_serviceProvider);
        });
        await messageHandler.Ready;
        _workerWitness.IsWorkerReady = true;
    }
```

But here I don't know how to set the AutoDelete flag. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [follow the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/), on configuring consumers with a container, you would see that you can configure your consumers so that they are resolved from the container as shown below (your code, updated to be correct):

```csharp
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
    {
        config.Host(settings.RabbitMq.Host, settings.RabbitMq.Port,
            settings.RabbitMq.VirtualHost, h =>
        {
            h.Username(settings.RabbitMq.Username);
            h.Password(settings.RabbitMq.Password);
        });

        var queueName = AssembleQueueName(settings);

        config.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, e =>
        {
            e.AutoDelete = true;
            
            e.ConfigureConsumer<MessageConsumer>(context);
        });
    }));
});
```